# Vlookup and SUM of duplicate values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, sumifs, gs-vlookup

I was working on a Google Spreadsheet, containing two sheets which are "[Main](http://i.epvpimg.com/FzMDd.png)" and "[WIP](http://i.epvpimg.com/sye2c.png)".

WIP sheet contains all the raw Data that I need. While on the Main Sheet, I was trying to get the exact data from WIP sheet using Vlookup function. I used this working formula for that:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,WIP!$A$1:$E$996,2,FALSE),"-")
```

My problem is, there is a duplicate product code on WIP sheet. What I need to do is get the sum of those and the total appear on the Main sheet.

The Value of product code **B11HVYJK** on the Main Sheet should be:

```
Available    Inbound
   51           9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `=SUM(FILTER(WIP!B:B,WIP!A:A=$A2))`